# Java - Enumerable.Cast() like C#?

Tags: java, generics, casting, java-5

Is there an equivalent in Java 1.5 to [`Enumerable.Cast()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341406.aspx) from C#?  I want to assign an `ArrayList<MyType>` to a variable declared as `List<Object>`.  Eclipse grumbles "Type mismatch:  cannot convert from `ArrayList<MyType>` to `List<Object>`".  I was just using `List` and `ArrayList` without generics but the compiler warns about that, and I wanted to clean up some warnings.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It would be unsafe to cast that if you were going to *add* to the list. However, if you only want to *fetch* from the list you can use:

```
ArrayList<MyType> specificList = new ArrayList<MyType>();
List<? extends Object> generalList = specificList;
```

Or closer to `Enumerable.Cast` would be to use `Iterable`:

```
Iterable<? extends Object> generalIterable = specificList;
```

It's a shame that you even need to specify the wildcard here (I was surprised that you did) given that `Iterable` is a "read only" interface.

For a lot more information on Java generics, see the [Java Generics FAQ](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/JavaGenericsFAQ.html).

Comment: Thanks!  I adjusted some return and parameter types to have `<? extends Object>` instead of `<Object>` and everything is happy now.

Comment: @SarahVessels: Using wildcards for parameter types is fine (and what they're for, primarily), but you want to try to avoid using them in return types when possible.

Comment: @ColinD:  I might update my classes that I'm expecting as the return type to share an interface, so I can have a return type of `List<InterfaceMyClassesImplement>`.